# FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need to query some data based on the uid of the currently signed in user. I have an *auth service* with a *user$* observable:

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user => {
    // logged in
    if (user){
      return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
    }
    // logged out
    else {
      return of(null)
    }
  })
```

I then have a *photo service* which queries the data, using the uid from the *user$* observable:

```
photos: Observable<Photo[]>;

uid;

constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore, private auth:AuthService) {
  this.auth.user$.subscribe(user => this.uid = user.uid);

  this.photos = this.afs.collection('photos',
  ref => ref.where('uid','==',this.uid).orderBy('createdAt','asc')).valueChanges();
}

getPhotos(){
  return this.photos;
}
```

Finally, I have a component that subscribes to the *photos* observable from the *photos service*:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.photoservice.getPhotos().subscribe(photos => this.photos = photos);
}
```

When I run the code I get the error: *FirebaseError: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined.* I think it is because the query runs before I can get the uid. How can I get the uid before I run the query?

Comment: I think the question is actually how you can **defer** the query until after the uid becomes available from the Firebase Auth state observer.

Comment: I suggest to include your logic behind the routing, as mentioned by Doug, it seems that you're trying to retrieve an invalid value of the uid. A correction on the logic of your App should correct that so try this: Login -> Redirect/Reroute -> get the photos collection